# Get select version in "item:versionAdded" events

Tags: sxa, versions

We would like to get select version from Experience Editor in item:versionAdded event. Kindly take a look at the attached image.

[image]

In the above image when we select "version 2: then We can get it in item:versionAdded event in the code.

Comment: We need to get select version in the code so suggested question did not help us.

Comment: No event is called when you changed the version. It's only a javascript code which opens another url with selected version included as parameter (as explained in the other question).

Comment: Yes its true but When we select version from the above image and after that add new version by clicking on Add then we are calling this event item:versionAdded and need to get selected version details.

Comment: So assuming you have 4 versions of an item, you currently edit 2nd version in Experience Editor and you click "Add version" to create 5th version, you would like to get "2" cause you have version 2 opened in Experience Editor now?

Comment: yes , we need to get 2nd version with your example. However, we are getting latest version in this case.